# Append text to cell value based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula to combine several values:

1. Value in column C
2. Add 'And' if there is a space
3. Drop down selection value in column I
4. Assigned value based on dropdown selection in column I (e.g. B1, C1)
5. Append B1 or C1 to value in column C, result shown in column M

The formula in column M:

```html
=IF(I15="Truck",CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and ","And"),CHAR(32),"")),IF(I15="Bus",CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),CHAR(32),"")& "B1"),IF(I15="Car",CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),CHAR(32),"")),"")& "C1"))
```

It works except for one tiny part; whenever the value in column C is blank, `C1` is populated into column M by default. The value in column M should be blank.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *real* issue is when `I15` is blank.  Run through with the "Evaluate Formula" tool, and you should see it, but if you break your code out and format it with indentations/new lines, etc:

```
=IF(I15="Truck",
    CLEAN(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and ","And"), 'Should this be "and" rather than "and " to match the "Bus" and "Car"?
            CHAR(32),
            ""
        )
    ),
    IF(I15="Bus",
        CLEAN(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),
                CHAR(32),
                ""
            )& "B1"
        ),
        IF(I15="Car",
            CLEAN(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),
                    CHAR(32),
                    ""
                )
            ), 'Should this bracket be after the "C1" instead of here?
            ""
        )& "C1"
    )
)
```

Now, trace through if `I15` is blank:  `I15` is not "Truck" and `I15` is not "Bus", so we get:

```
=IF(FALSE,
    N/A,
    IF(FALSE,
        N/A,
        IF(I15="Car",
            CLEAN(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),
                    CHAR(32),
                    ""
                )
            ), 'Should this bracket be after the "C1" instead of here?
            ""
        )& "C1"
    )
)
```

Simplify that down, and you get:

```
IF(I15="Car",
    CLEAN(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),
            CHAR(32),
            ""
        )
    ),
    ""
)& "C1"
```

But, `I15` is blank, not "Car", so it becomes `IF(FALSE, N/A, "") & "C1"` - meaning, it will always say "C1" if `I15` is not "Bus" or "Truck".

Also, you probably can simplify your code down to `=CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C15),"and","And"),CHAR(32),"")) & IF(I15="Bus", "B1", IF(I15="Car", "C1", ""))`

If you can set up a table somewhere, you can change the `IF` statement to a `VLOOKUP`, or if you have a table for the Drop-down values you can use `CHOOSE(MATCH(..))`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the simplified code you have shared works great. Appreciate your patience.